# Creating a hash-value of a directory in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, hash, filesystems

Is there any mean to determine if the directory content (including deep subdirectory structure) has changed since last access? I'm looking for a portable solution in C/C++, preferably in Qt.

P.S.:
If relevant, the background of the question.
In my application I have to scan recursively many directories and import some data in a database, when some conditions are true. Once the directory was imported, I mark it with a file ".imported" and ignore next times.

Now I want to mark also scanned but not imported directories. For this I'd store a file  containing a directory hash. So, prior to scan I could compare the hash calculated with the last hash in file and skip scanning if they are equal.

Comment: Why are some directories scanned but not imported? Imported directories are considered static after that, right (otherwise, the flag won't make sense)? What changes are you looking for? Also, how would you calculate the hash prior to scanning? I think, I am missing something in your question.

Comment: Maybe simple modification time check of all files and directories is sufficient?
You can save the time of a scan and compare with it when you need to test if you need another scan.

Comment: @TilmanVogel: I'm scanning for completeness of data. The directories are used by 3 programs. One creates data, another analyses and annotates data and finally one that transfers data to DB. Only completely annotated data is transferred to DB. The annotation may take several days and it may be done in several sessions, not at once. Only if an xml file for all data-files exists, the annotation is considered as complete. Jes, after DB-transfer the directory is "sealed".

Comment: @userr1728854: yes looks a good way to go. I hoped there is something ready to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfilesystemwatcher.html) class that will notify you of changes.

If you want to create a Cryptographic Hash of a directory and its contents, this is how I do it: -

```
void AddToHash(const QFileInfo& fileInf, QCryptographicHash& cryptHash)
{
    QDir directory(fileInf.absoluteFilePath());
    directory.setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files);
    QFileInfoList fileInfoList = directory.entryInfoList();

    foreach(QFileInfo info, fileInfoList)
    {
        if(info.isDir())
        {   
            // recurse through all directories
            AddToHash(info, cryptHash);
            continue;
        }

        // add all file contents to the hash
        if(info.isFile())
        {
            QFile file(info.absoluteFilePath());
            if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            {      
                // failed to open file, so skip              
                continue;
            }
            cryptHash.addData(&file);
            file.close();
        }
    }
}

// create a fileInfo from the top-level directory
QFileInfo fileInfo(filePath);
QString hash;
// Choose an arbitrary hash, say Sha1
QCryptographicHash cryptHash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
// add all files to the hash
AddToHash(fileInfo, cryptHash);
// get a printable version of the hash
hash = cryptHash.result().toHex();
```

Comment: This will however only help if you keep watching all the time. Also, if I remember correctly, creating a large number of watchers for watching a whole hierarchy can be quite a resource hog especially on Windows.

Comment: That's true, so I've updated the answer to include a method of getting a directory hash with Qt ;O)

Comment: +1 That looks good and is pretty fast! Besides some small typos seems to work (AddtoHash vs AddToHash and cryptHash.addData(&file) ). I'll test is thoroughly next days and select the answer. Two modifications I'll try out are: using timestamp for hash, not the content and using file-filter (in my case only xml files may change).

Comment: I've corrected the AddToFile typo; thanks for pointing it out. Let me know how it goes ;O)